# ways to hacker can access my Firebase Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I know anyone can see database url from `google-services.json` in android application just by extract apk.

I think, If we hide `childName` reference of `db` then hacker can not access database. Or any other way to access data from only `db url`?

In this case, My security rules are public.

Here is view of my database(this is dummy project).
[image]

after db url, hacker must need `child names`, we can hide this(I know can not hide 100% secure but we can make hard to find for hacker".
[image]
He need need again child name to access.
[image]

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do. --- Please also apply this to other text: text should be shown as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: Is it feasible to use serverless execution environment such as cloud function to retrieve entries from Firestore Database, instead of client directly accessing the database thru Firestore API with the given collection or document path?

My rationale is that with this method, the specified path (or db url) lives in the code I wrote in the cloud function and stays in server, not exposed to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current rules, a malicious user needs to only know the URL of your database to access all data in it. Seriously, try this: https://icaptcha-bfc94-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.json.

---

If you want to make it slightly harder for them to read the data, at the very least change your rules to only allow access to the specific named node:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "PayoutDays": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

Now they will have to know the name `PayoutDays` before they can access the data.

---

One additional step would be to include a less guessable value in the path, for example:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "PayoutDays-asdhuqw9nnuucxzksdb21872nn1n": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

The key name is now a lot less guessable, so it's less likely that a malicious user can guess it.

---

But here still the problem is that anyone who uses your app can see the keys it loads, and thus use that to reproduce the access. To make that harder, consider [implementing App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) *and* (as Doug said in his answer) [authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) (even if only [anonymous auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth)) and [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security).

Comment: I was missing that `dburl/.json` . Great examples, Now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Security rules are the only way to truly secure access to only those Firebase Auth accounts that should be able to access it.  Anything else (including your suggestion of "hiding childName reference") is just making it harder to access, but that's not really security at all.

Again, security rules are the **only** way to go if you want real security and not just obfuscation. Either that, or lock down your database rules and provide some other truly secure means to allow access to it.

See also:

- [Firebase Realtime Database Security for Private Single-Developer User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64589887/firebase-realtime-database-security-for-private-single-developer-user)
- [Firebase RealTime Database Security Rules for personal app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75434711/firebase-realtime-database-security-rules-for-personal-app)